# Left join with junction table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following tables :-

```
- Visit
- Vehicles
- VehicleVisits (junction table of the above two)
```

i want a linq query to left join visits table with VehicleVisits 
like this :

```
from workOrder in dbContext.WorkOrders 
join visit in dbContext.Visits on workOrder.VisitID equals visit.ID         
from v in visit.Vehicles into leftJoin
from  leftJoin1 in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

but this query is not true

 
what can i do?

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your help